# How load image to server use POST, multipart/form-data(android)

Tags: android, post, https, multipartform-data

Sorry for my english. Today i try load image in server use post request and multipart/form-data. It is very heavily for me. This is example request:

```
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="imageName.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

Bellow i create method, which send image to server. But server say me: no, its error

```
public static String executeHttpLoadImage(String url, String nameValueF, String paramValueF, String nameValueS, String paramValueS,
                                                String filePath, String fileName) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = createHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(); //post
            request.setURI(new URI(url));

            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); //set header
            request.setHeader(nameValueF, paramValueF);               //set header
            request.setHeader(nameValueS, paramValueS);               //set header

            //set multipart
            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();        //multipart
            File file = new File(filePath);                          //file path
            ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");   //body
            mpEntity.addPart(fileName, cbFile);                      //add

            request.setEntity(mpEntity);
            //set multipart

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `This is example request`. OK. But is that yours? There are no file bytes included. Empty file! How does yours look like?

Comment: `mpEntity.addPart(fileName, cbFile);`. What is the value of `fileName`? It should be `mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile); ` if you want to do it according your example.

Comment: @greenapps @greenapps yes, its my example. I have class `CustomHttpClient` and then contains all method url what i need. This is example what i use this: `json = new JSONObject(CustomHttpClient.executeHttpLoadImage(
                        "https://example.com/image", "id", "1111",
                        "key", "2222",
                        params[0], "image1"));` and `params[0]` its file path image